# How to name an array with a variable in java?

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to make a calendar in Java that will store events such as doctors appointment, etc. I plan on storing these events as String arrays, containing the name of the event, the location of the event, and the time of the event. In order to generate new events, however, the arrays need to have unique names which I want to be the date they occur on. To do this, I planned on making a method that would take a new name for the array as a variable and then use that variable as the name of the array (as below):

```
public static void addInformation(String eventLabel) {
    String eventName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What yould you like the event to be called?");
    String eventLocation = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Where will this event take place?");
    String eventTime = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What time will this event take place? Input as: \"hours:minutes\" using a 24 hour clock.");
    String[] eventLabel = {eventName, eventLocation, eventTime};
    events.add(newEvent);
}
```

When I try this, I get an error saying: eventLabel is already defined in addInformation(java.lang.String)

Is there any way to name an array with a variable using a parameter? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

It seems you cannot have a variable variable name. Is there a way to create a unique array each time this method is called?

Comment: You cannot have variable variable names in Java.

Comment: What is the type of `events` ?

Comment: It's an array list of arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `HashMap`. For each entry, set the key using the `eventLabel` parameter, and value as  your array. This way, you will have a name for each of your "arrays" (which will be an entry in the `HashMap`, in this case).

Answer (score 1):

Your method declaration has `eventLabel` as type `String`. You try to redefine it as `String[]`. Try `String[] eventLabelArray`.

Hot Licks is correct - you **cannot** do something like `addInformation('Arr')` and have `eventLabel` be named `'Arr'` and call `Arr[0]`. Why do you need it to be variable?

Comment: I tried that but it just leads me to the same problem in a different part of the code: I still need to name the array using a variable.

Comment: If you are looking to name an array with the passed variable string, see @HotLicks comment.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is like using a variable name to create a variable name, I am not sure if this can be done.

But Maps can be used to solve your problem.Maps will provide your exactly same functionality as you want

for example:

```
Map<String, Something> myMap = new HashMap<String, Something>();

String name = eventName + eventLocation + eventTime; 

 myMap.put(name, new something);
```

Answer (score 0):

`eventLabel` is used as both a local variable in the method as well as a passed-in argument. Give the two different names and that should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the same name as the variable passed (`String eventLavel`) to your function

```
public static void addInformation(String eventLabel){
  String eventName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"What yould you like the event to be called?");
  String eventLocation = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Where will this event take place?");
  String eventTime = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "What time will this event take place? Input as: \"hours:minutes\" using a 24 hour clock.");
  String[] arr = {eventName, eventLocation, eventTime}; // some other name!
  events.add(arr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good you're thinking about things this way, but I think you're trying to solve a non-problem.

> Is there a way to create a unique array each time this method is
>   called?

Yes, it happens for free - you don't have to do anything.  Because the array is being created inside the method, a new one gets created every time.  So as others have said, just use a different variable name (not `eventLabel`) and you're good to go.

Comment: Well even if the new array is being created, if I am appending that array to an array list, how do I distinguish between each item?

Comment: @user3224584 Sorry, missed the big picture.  As other folks said - use a Map (HashMap).